# Trying to loop Phaser 3 scene only specific time

Tags: javascript, for-loop, phaser-framework

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  this.time.addEvent({
    delay: 300,
    loop: false,
    callback: () => {
      this.scene.start("scene1");
    }
  })
}
```

Here is my another scene, I am trying to loop the scene back to scene 1 only for specific time but the for loop do not work. It still loop the scene infinitely. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are  calling the `time` event multiple times, in the `for`- loop, and you can only call `start` once on the same `scene`.

This causes an Error, when the `time` event is executed the second time (asynchronous). Since the function `start` *shutdowns the current scene* = `this`(details [in the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scenes.ScenePlugin.html#start__anchor)).

*Why are you calling it multiple times `this.scene.start("scene1");` in the `for`-loop? This doesn't make sense.*

**Update:**
*(Just a small demo showing automatic switching)*

```js
  let SCENES_KEYS = ['SceneOne', 'SceneTwo', 'SceneThree'];
  let current_scene_index = 0;

  class SceneTimeSwitcher extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor (config) {
        super(config);
    }

    create () {
        this.time.addEvent({
            delay: 1000,
            loop: false,
            callback: () => {
                current_scene_index++;
                if(current_scene_index >= SCENES_KEYS.length){
                    current_scene_index = 0;
                }
                this.scene.start(SCENES_KEYS[current_scene_index]);
            }
        })
    }
}


class SceneOne extends SceneTimeSwitcher {
    constructor (config) {
        super('SceneOne');
    }

    create () {
        super.create();
        this.add.text(20,20, 'SCENE ONE');
    }
}

class SceneTwo extends SceneTimeSwitcher {
    constructor (config) {
        super('SceneTwo');
    }

    create () {
        super.create();
        this.add.text(20,20, 'SCENE TWO');
    }
}

class SceneThree extends SceneTimeSwitcher {
    constructor (config) {
        super('SceneThree');
    }

    create () {
        super.create();
        this.add.text(20,20, 'SCENE THREE');
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: [ SceneOne, SceneTwo, SceneThree ]
};

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ty for the reply.So i have 3 scene in total, is there anyway to loop all three scene in like several times?
...Start... function only run 1 time
...Update... function run infinite times

Comment: @NgJiaYong I added some code in my answer, it shows how you could cycle through Scenes, it is abit long but should work solid.

Comment: how about stop the scene when it switched a specific times like 5 set of the scenes?

Comment: @NgJiaYong you could make a global variable like `current_scene_index` and call in `let max_loop_count = 0;` and in the `create` method you increase the variable  `max_loop_count++` and only create a new `time` event, when **max_loop_count** less then **5**. I hope this information helps

Answer (score -1):

```
if (loop < 5) {
 this.time.addEvent({
  delay: 3000,
  loop: false,
  callback: () => {
    loop++;
    this.scene.start("scene1");
  }
 })
}
```

Solved with the code above. Incrementation placed inside callback